# javafx - how to convert a node to another object

Tags: java, object, javafx, line, scene

I'm sorry, I can't find a way around this. I have to get a "Node" object to be a "Line" object. What I mean is this:
I have an AnchorPane filled with quite a lot of nodes, some of them Labels and the majority of them Lines. Setting that up works nice and well, but later in my code I need the coordinates of those Lines. What I tried was this (explanation below):

```
List<Line> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Node currentNode : anchorPaneGame.getChildren()){
        if (currentNode.getTypeSelector().equals("Line")){
            lineList.add(currentNode);
        }
```

I made a List where I wanted to collect all the Lines, however this didn't work because (I'll just quote my IDE): "add (javafx.scene.shape.Line) in List cannot be applied to (java.fx.scene.Node)".
Befor that I tried to do

```
Line tempLine = apGame.getChildren().get(apGame.getChildren().size()-1);
```

And got the same error of course (I know for a fact that the last element is a Line, adding it as the last thing is hard coded). The reason I'm doing all this is to do `.getEndX()` at the end - the very first thing I tried was

```
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(borderPane, apGame.getChildren().get(apGame.getChildren().size()-1).getEndX());
```

This was supposed to set the the Borderpane right at the end of the last Line that could be found in the AnchorPane `apGame`. But because `.getChildren` returns only Nodes it didn't know that it was dealing with a Line and therefor couldn't resolve `.getEndX()`.
Do you have any ideas how I can make the programm realize that a given Node is infact a Line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `instanceof` in conjunction with a downcast:

```
List<Line> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Node currentNode : anchorPaneGame.getChildren()){
    if (currentNode instanceof Line){
        lineList.add((Line)currentNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was _exactly_ what I was looking for! I knew there had to be a simple, smart and tricky way to do that